# awk remove \n if next line doesn't match

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /\.[log(message|event)|trace(error)?c?|infoc?|warnc?|debugc?|errorc?]/,/)/{gsub(/^\t+/, "", $0);print NR","$0}' example_file
```

I created this script that finds in a file for patterns like:

```
log.Info("hello world")
log.Error()
```

And outputs something like:

```
4,log.Info("hello world")
7,log.Error()
```

The line number and the text itself.

The thing is that if I have something like this on my file:

```
log.Info("hello world")
log.Warn(
    "hello world")
log.Error()
```

It will output something like this:

```
4,log.Info("hello world")
5,log.Warn(
6,"hello world")
7,log.Error()
```

I wanted to make `"hello world")` the same line as `log.Warn(`.

Like if the next line found doesn't start with the pattern `/\.[log(message|event)|trace(error)?c?|infoc?|warnc?|debugc?|errorc?]/` it will put this line on the line before that.

The desired output would be something like:

```
4,log.Info("hello world")
5,log.Warn("hello world")
7,log.Error()
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus Hi there. I did that actually. "The thing is that if I have something like this on my file" has the sample and the desired output is the last portion of the question. I didn't get what you mean, sorry.

Comment: `/\.[log(me` that is a very odd regex, that's not how it works. `gsub(/^\t+/, "", $0)` no, you wouldn't be able to do ia simple. The problem is how you phrased the condition: `if the  **next line** found` If you are deciding actions on _the next line_, that means that you _have to_ buffer your data. Writre something that depends on _current line_, no ton the next, like "if current line does not end with )".

Comment: @KamilCuk I made using regex101, like this: https://regex101.com/r/YMvp01/1

Comment: Well, yes, it's a valid regex. No, _bracket expression_ does not choose one of expression inside and `|` is a normal character inside it. Your regex is the same as `[()?abcdefgilmnorstuvw|]`. `[...]` is not `(..)`

Comment: @ZefexDeveloper regex101 helps you  create a regexp that's syntactically valid **on that web site**. What it doesn't do is ensure that regexp does what you want or even makes any sense, nor that it's syntactically valid or will behave the same way in any command-line tool. So it's usefulness is limited at best!

Comment: What you're trying to do is generally impossible to do robustly without writing a parser for whatever language your input file is written in as it needs to consider cases like `log.Warn("foo\"bar(etc)bar\"foo")` where your strings can contain characters that are the string delimiters (`"`) and/or the function are delimiters (`(` and `)`) so are you OK with a solution that's just a best-effort and will fail for some cases?

Comment: Got it, you guys are right. I actually changed from `[...]` to `(...)` but the main goal remains. The usage of `gsub` is that I want to trim the beginning of the line.

Comment: @EdMorton That is sad. And yes, I'm ok with a best-effort solution for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a best-effort script (i.e. will fail in various rainy-day cases), using this input file:

```
$ cat file
foo
log.Info("hello
        world")
log.Warn(
    "hello
                some other
        world")
log.Error()
bar
```

and any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    begRe = "log[.](Info|Warn|Error)[(]"
    regexp = begRe "[^)]*[)]"
    OFS = ","
}
$0 ~ begRe {
    begNr = NR
    buf = ""
}
begNr {
    buf = buf $0
    if ( match(buf,regexp) ) {
        buf = substr(buf,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/[[:space:]]*"[[:space:]]*/,"\"",buf)
        print begNr, buf
        begNr = 0
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2,log.Info("hello       world")
4,log.Warn("hello               some other      world")
8,log.Error()
```

if you want to collapse all the white space within quotes and remove any leading white space then just add `gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",buf); gsub(/^ | $/,"",buf)` before the print statement.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    begRe = "log[.](Info|Warn|Error)[(]"
    regexp = begRe "[^)]*[)]"
    OFS = ","
}
$0 ~ begRe {
    begNr = NR
    buf = ""
}
begNr {
    buf = buf $0
    if ( match(buf,regexp) ) {
        buf = substr(buf,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/[[:space:]]*"[[:space:]]*/,"\"",buf)
        gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",buf); gsub(/^ | $/,"",buf)
        print begNr, buf
        begNr = 0
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2,log.Info("hello world")
4,log.Warn("hello some other world")
8,log.Error()
```

Answer (score 2):

> Like if the **next line** found doesn't start with the pattern /.[log(message|event)|trace(error)?c?|infoc?|warnc?|debugc?|errorc?]/ it will put this line on the line before that.

You can't make actions depending on the next line, you can only make actions depending on the current line. Which basically means that you have to:

- buffer one line (previous line)
- if the current line does start with the pattern /.[log(message|event)|trace(error)?c?|infoc?|warnc?|debugc?|errorc?]/ output previous line. Previous line becomes current line.
- otherwise, output previous line and current line. Previous line becopmes empty.
- END { output previous line }

Something along:

```
awk '
    /^log\./{  # the pattern here
       if (last) {
         print NR - 1, last;  # output previous line
        }
       last=$0  # previous line becomes current line
       next
    }
    { # otherwise, because next above
       print NR - 1, last $0   # output previous line and current line
       last=""  # previous line becomes empty.
    }
    END{
      if (last) {
        print NR, last  # Handle previous line on the end.
      }
    }
'
```

Change your condition, so it depends on "current line" only. Like, if current line does not end with `)`, eat next line.

```
awk '/[^)]$/{
   n=NR
   a=$0
   getline
   print n " " a $0
}'
```